# best_in_place under namespace controller is returning 404 when POST

Tags: ruby-on-rails, best-in-place

I implemented `best_in_place` gem according to [#302 In-Place Editing screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/302-in-place-editing?view=asciicast).

Views are located under `admin/users`.

Given this code on a page

```
= best_in_place @user, :admin, type: :input
```

The result renders ok and it changes its status to editable field when clicked but when try to save the value I can see this error

```
POST http://localhost:3000/admin/users 404 (Not Found)
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

I was using `$('.custom-selector').best_in_place()` instead of internal 
`$('.best_in_place').best_in_place()`